# Having ordered pairs as parameters in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, parameters

I am trying to write a program that accepts two points (ordered pairs) as parameters and returns the Euclidean distance between these points.

However, I am having trouble creating parameters that are ordered pairs. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you add an example: how to run the program and what the output is?

Comment: So the input parameters would be two ordered pairs (x1, y1) and (x2, y2). The program would calculate the distance between these two points using: (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)

Answer (score 0):

```
P1=(1,3)
P2=(9,27)

def dist(p1, p2):
    '''
    comment...
    '''
    return (p2[1] - p2[0])/(p1[1] - p1[0])

print(dist(P1, P2))
```

Comment: @user208587  if this is the answer you should mark is as such.